# Windows phone 8.1 in app purchase fails

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I had this problem so I thought I'd post the answer since I couldn't find the solution anywhere.

**First problem:** when calling CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync() I would get "Can't find item in catalog ; We looked but can't find the item you wanted to buy" or error 805a0194.

**Second problem:** Couldn't find a way to get if my purchase was active or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution to problem one:** go to your Package.appxmanifest and right click then hit view code. if your app was already published like mine was go to the dashboard and get the AppId from the Windows Phone dashboard->apps->YourApp->Details. Paste that id into the PhoneProductId field in the Package.appxmanifest. Now your in app purchases should work as long as you published the product in the store and product id you supplied to the method matches.

**Solution to Problem 2:** I used this bit of code to see if the purchase was active:

```
private async Task<bool> GetLicenseStatus(string id)
{
    try
    {
        var result = await   CurrentApp.GetProductReceiptAsync(id);
    }

    catch //user didnt buy
    {
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hello. I need your help. I have WP8.1 app with ability to make in-app purchases. I created In-App Product via Dashboard, publish it. Then in my app I specified this productId, but after I update my app (with new logic to make in-app purchases), I get "Can't find item in catalog". What should I do to resolve it?